Why would the "dirichletprocess" package in R return the number of clusters of the last MCMC iteration?
I've been working with the "dirichletprocess" package in R, specifically trying to recreate the example shown in the vignette where they cluster the eruptions in the Old Faithful dataset using a Dirichlet Process Mixture Model (DPMM). However, I've run into a few issues, and I'm curious if anyone else has experienced the same concerns.
The number of clusters in this package is defined as the number of clusters in the last iteration of the MCMC routine. In my experience, this feels a bit counterproductive. I've noticed that the traceplot of the number of clusters oscillates a lot, and because of this, the last value could be anywhere between 2 and 5 clusters. This variability makes the final result somewhat arbitrary.
In the vignette, they conveniently avoid showing any traceplots, only the final clustering result with 2 (correct) clusters. But if you run the same code, you can sometimes end up with 3 clusters, where one of them has just one or two points, which is expected due to the random nature in the sampling process. However, it raises the question: how reliable is the last iteration as an indicator of the true number of clusters? Why would the author make this choice?
In my case, I am using a $Gamma(1,1)$ prior for the concentration parameter $α$. The traceplots I get show the number of clusters oscillating quite a bit, with an average of around 2.31 clusters. Even using the default prior configuration gives similar results, which seems unstable. I would expect the model to more consistently detect 2 clusters, since it looks like a pretty trivial example, but that doesn't seem to be happening, even when using 2000 iterations. Are DPMM that inconsistent, after all?
Has anyone dealt with a similar issue or found a way to make the results more stable?

"Why would they do this" is a question that probably only the package authors can answer. I see the package has a GitHub page, you would likely get a better answer by asking a question there (probably reworded a bit to be a touch less accusatory).

Unfortunately, the author seems inactive on GitHub, at least for the past year or so. I'm not really accusing anyone, just posing a rhetorical question for which someone may have some more insight on.
